# UICollectionView how to reloadData from delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am trying to reload my collectionView from my delegate method "applicationDidEnterForeground" but i got an error ""UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter"

in my **CollectionViewController** I have this method

```
-(void)reloadThisData
{
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

and here is my code in the **appDelegate**

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    CollectionViewController *collectionViews = [[CollectionViewController alloc]init];

    [collectionViews reloadThisData];
}
```

i know that it will only create another collectionView that is why it will only return a null value. is there any other way to reload my uiviewcollection from background to foreground?

Comment: can you provide code?

Comment: thank you for your reply, Please take a look at my question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the error that you get you need to initialise CollectionViewController with a flow layout.

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout* flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
CollectionViewController * collectionViews = [[CollectionViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
[collectionViews reloadThisData];
```

**I would recommend a different approach to doing this though**, as in your app delegate you would be creating a new instance of CollectionViewController and not targeting the displayed one. 
You should subscribe to "UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification" notification in your viewWillAppear method in CollectionViewController.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadThisData) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}
```

Don't forget to remove the observer too so that duplicate calls aren't made to the reload method.

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}
```